# (How) Can I filter out closed questions?

Tags: support

As far as I can tell, the "custom filter" offers no such option. Is there another way I am missing?

To be specific, I'd like to modify the list of questions on https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/ to only include questions that are not yet marked with "[closed]".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is described on [meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125235/how-to-search-for-closed-questions) You can filter for only closed questions by adding `closed:1` to your search terms. Conversely if you use the search term `closed:0` you can search only for open questions.

As pointed out by VLAZ there's documentation about [advanced search options](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/searching) in the [Help Center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is no way to exclude closed posts using a custom filter.

You can still use the site search for that. The search text needed is `is:q closed:no` which will give you only questions which are not closed. The result can further be sorted by newest or by score.

For more filters and search options see [the help centre article on searching](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/searching).